# angular post to obtain access token failed

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, http, oauth

would you guys help me to create an angularjs POST request version

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6weCtBHDZU1eUFWcHpNNE5WTVk/view?usp=sharing.

The idea is to obtain an access token so i can securely consume some rest apis.
I tried many times through the post via angular, i analyzed every request and i failed, i always found that the request body is empty.

Here is an example of some angular codes that i tried.

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app
        .controller(
                "MyController",
                function($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.obtain_token = function() {
                        var payload = "grant_type=password" + "&username=roy" + "&password=spring" +
                          "&client_id=clientapp"+
                          "&client_secret=123456";
                        var r = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token',payload);
                        r.success(function(response){
                            console.log(response.access_token);
                        });
                    };
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function Hello($scope, $http) {

    var config = {
            headers : {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' +btoa('clientapp:123456654321')
            }
        }
    var payload ="password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp";

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token',payload, config).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You should also explain what is wrong and what you changed. Not only post the function. (and format it better)

Comment: he forgot headers, you can see image from google drive that he attach

Comment: the code that adsl Le suggested is working and fine when it's about the same application. The problem is that the resource that i'm trying to consume is hosted at **localhost:8080** and i'm trying to requesting it from  another application hosted at **localhost:8090**. Is this possible from the front-office

Answer (score 0):

```
sample angular-1 code..
----------------------------------
var payload = {
"grant_type":"password",
"username"="roy",
"password"="spring",
"client_id"="clientapp"
"client_secret"="123456"
}

$http.post("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", payload).success(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }).error(function(error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            });

and sample api c#
---------------------
[HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveArchive([FromBody] JObject saveRequest)
        {
            var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try``
            {
                return "your success message";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return ex;
            }
        }
```